# Why do parameters passed by reference in C++ not require a dereference operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm new to the C++ community, and just have a quick question about how C++ passes variables by reference to functions.

When you want to pass a variable by reference in C++, you add an `&` to whatever argument you want to pass by reference.  How come when you assign a value to a variable that is being passed by reference why do you say `variable = value;` instead of saying `*variable = value`?

```
void add_five_to_variable(int &value) {
    // If passing by reference uses pointers,
    // then why wouldn't you say *value += 5?
    // Or does C++ do some behind the scene stuff here?
    value += 5; 
} 

int main() {

  int i = 1;
  add_five_to_variable(i);
  cout << i << endl; // i = 6

  return 0;
}
```

If C++ is using pointers to do this with behind the scenes magic, why aren't dereferences needed like with pointers?  Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write,

```
int *p = ...;
*p = 3;
```

That is syntax for assigning 3 to the object referred to by the pointer `p`.  When you write,

```
int &r = ...;
r = 3;
```

That is syntax for assigning 3 to the object referred to by the reference `r`.  The syntax and the implementation are different.  References are implemented using pointers (except when they're optimized out), but the syntax is different.

So you could say that the dereferencing happens automatically, when needed.

Comment: +1, for mentioning the difference between the syntax and implementation.

Answer (score 2):

C++ uses pointers behind the scenes but hides all that complication from you. Passing by reference also enables you to avoid all the problems asssoicated with invalid pointers.

Comment: It only avoids some of the problems with invalid pointers.  It's easy to create a reference to a local that goes out of scope, for example, which is an ages-old mistake with pointers.

Comment: @Ed: actually, the implementation of references is not specified, and completely left to the compiler. What is specified is that a reference may be optimized out by the compiler. So I would not say that they are pointers.

Comment: @Dietrich, pointer can also point to an out of scope local variable. I think this answer is correct. +1 from me.

Comment: @iammilind: "avoid all the problems asssoicated with invalid pointers" is certainly incorrect, "C++ uses pointers behind the scenes" is a sweeping generalization that contradicts the Standard and is certainly incorrect... the only part I agree with is "hides all that complication from you" :/

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an object to a function by reference, you manipulate the object directly in the function, without referring to its address like with pointers. Thus, when manipulating this variable, you don't want to dereference it with the `*variable` syntax. This is good practice to pass objects by reference because:

- A reference can't be redefined to point to another object
- It can't be null. you have to pass a valid object of that type to the function

How the compiler achieves the "pass by reference" is not really relevant in your case.

The [article in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) is a good ressource.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions in one, it seems:

- one question is about syntax: the difference between pointer and reference
- the other is about mechanics and implementation: the in-memory representation of a reference

Let's address the two separately.

**Syntax of references and pointers**

A pointer is, conceptually, a "sign" (as road sign) toward an object. It allows 2 kind of actions:

- actions on the pointee (or object pointed to)
- actions on the pointer itself

The `operator*` and `operator->` allow you to access the pointee, to differenciate it from your accesses to the pointer itself.

A reference is not a "sign", it's an alias. For the duration of its life, come hell or high water, it will point to the same object, nothing you can do about it. Therefore, since you cannot access the reference itself, there is no point it bothering you with weird syntax `*` or `->`. Ironically, not using weird syntax is called syntactic sugar.

**Mechanics of a reference**

The C++ Standard is silent on the implementation of references, it merely hints that if the compiler can it is allowed to *remove* them. For example, in the following case:

```
int main() {
  int a = 0;
  int& b = a;
  b = 1;
  return b;
}
```

A good compiler will realize that `b` is just a proxy for `a`, no room for doubts, and thus simply directly access `a` and optimize `b` out.

As you guessed, a likely representation of a reference is (under the hood) a pointer, but do not let it bother you, it does not affect the syntax or semantics. It does mean however that a number of woes of pointers (like access to objects that have been deleted for example) also affect references.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit dereference is not required by design - that's for convenience. When you use `.` on a reference the compiler emits code necessary to access the real object - this will often include dereferencing a pointer, but that's done without requiring an explicit dereference in your code.